# How do you upgrade your Spawning Pool?

Tags: a-game-of-dwarves

I'm stuck in the second tutorial mission of A Game of Dwarves.  I need to upgrade my spawning pool in order to recruit more dwarves, but I have no idea where to click in order to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click on the bottom right, where you see this round sphere with the image of a village, which represents Hemfort, the Town where all your dwarflings are coming from.

That opens a menu where you can upgrade your spawning pool.

[image]